# Python object identification (caching) different in the interactive window and script execution when using id() command?

Tags: python, object, caching

I know Python has a cache for objects with numerical values between -5 and 256. I can confirm this in Python interactive window (console). For example,

```
a = -10
b = -10
print(id(a))
1797396904912
print(id(b))
1797396904976
print(id(a) == id(b))
False
```

However, when I run exactly the same code via a script:

```
a = -10
b = -10
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
print(id(a) == id(b))
```

I get:

```
1797396904848
1797396904848
True
```

What's going on?
(The question has nothing to do with another question on id of strings with and without a space).

Comment: Not a duplicate. Completely different problem.

Comment: Why do you expect them to be the same?

Comment: Exactly the same code works differently in the interactive window and when it is run as a script. In one case, the objects are different. In the other, the id’s are the same.

Comment: The issue here, btw, is that Python will cache immutable literals in the same code block. When you execute as a module, they are in the same block. In a repl, these will be different blocks. This is all implementation details and could change unannounced at any moment

Answer (score 0):

No one seems to have an answer. I did a bit more exploration and found out that the problem exists in Anaconda but not in IDLE for a = -10 and b = -10.

However, the problem exists for c = 257 and d = 257. Different id(c) and id(d) when running in the interactive window. Same id(c) and id(d) when running IDLE script.